# CSS Styling: How can I recreate the iOS 14 Segment Control in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, styling

I'm trying recreate the iOS 14 Segment Control in React, but having an issue with the divider lines. How can I make the divider line next to the selected tab disappear?

I've tried extending the padding and margin to cover the lines, but issues with the first and last elements being too wide.

Can a CSS god help me out?

**Image (What I Have So Far):**
[image]

**Image (What it's supposed to look like):**
[image]

**Web Example**

https://laurasandoval.github.io/iOS13SegmentedControl/

**SegmentedControlYears.tsx**

```js
// Imports: Dependencies
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// Imports: TypeScript Types
import { SegmentedControlTabsYears } from '../types/types';

// TypeScript Type: Props
interface Props {
  tabs: Array<SegmentedControlTabsYears>,
  onSelection: (value: SegmentedControlTabsYears) => void,
};

// Component: Segmented Control (Years)
const SegmentedControlYears: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  // React Hooks: State
  const [ value, setValue ] = useState<SegmentedControlTabsYears>('2021');

  // Set Initial Tab
  useEffect(() => {
    // Set Data
    setValue(props.tabs[0] as SegmentedControlTabsYears);
  }, []);

  // Render Segment Tab Small Container Class Name
  const renderSegmentTabSmallContainerClassName = (tab: SegmentedControlTabsYears) => {
    // Selected Tab
    if (tab === value) {
      return 'segment-tab-years-container-selected';
    }
    // Unselected Tabs
    else {
      return 'segment-tab-years-container';
    }
  };

  return (
    <div id="segmented-control-years-container">
      <div id="segmented-control-years-track-container">
        <button className={renderSegmentTabSmallContainerClassName(tab)} onClick={() => setValue(tab)}>
          <p className=segment-tab-years-text">{tab}</p>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// Exports
export default SegmentedControlYears;
```

**SegmentedControlYears.css**

```css
#segmented-control-years-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

#segmented-control-years-track-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #272729;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.segment-tab-years-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 16px;
    width: 75px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #646368;
}

.segment-tab-years-container:last-child {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}

.segment-tab-years-container-selected{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 75px;
    background-color: #646368;
    border: none;
    border: 3px solid #272729;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.segment-tab-years-text{
    font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: .4px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```